# Rails 5 API not generating views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I started a new Rails 5 projeect with the `--api` tag.

I decided to have certain admin controls and for this I required views. I modified the base application controller to inherit from `ActionController::Base` instead of `ActionController::API`.

But it is still not working. I keep getting a routing error
[image]

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'review/index'

  get 'review/show'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
    scope module: 'api' do
        namespace :v1 do
            resources :articles, only: [:index, :show]
        end
    end
end
```

rails generate controller output

```
>$ rails g controller Review index show
      create  app/controllers/review_controller.rb
       route  get 'review/show'
       route  get 'review/index'
      invoke  test_unit
      create    test/controllers/review_controller_test.rb
```

It is not generating views, even though I manually created the folder and files.

**EDIT -

Ahh. Stupid me. I had generated the controller without adding plurality to the name. Convention is a strict mommy.**

`rails g controller reviews index show`

Comment: You've defined your routes in a wrong way. Try `resources :reviews, only: [:index, :create]`.

Comment: Those were auto generated. And changing them still doesn't work. I have restarted the server.

Answer (score 0):

You've created the project with the `--api` flag, which will not generate views for you (since it expects to just be an API). I suspect that you want to create the project without `--api` and just create some API-specific controllers manually.

Comment: You can definitely create a working view in API mode. I can't remember how from the top of my head, but it's definitely doable @arjun.

Comment: It *is* doable, but by defining the project with `--api`, the project is created without a bunch of things that views may expect to exist. I would start by changing the controller to `ActionController::Base` and then manually create the view files

Comment: @AlecSanger I Had already done that. Mentioned it in the post first thing.

Comment: Alright I got it working. Made edit to the question. Did not follow the naming convention. Thanks both of you.

Comment: If you visit `/review/index` does it load the page? You need to define your route as a resource or specifically point your `get review` to the proper controller if you want it to load without using `index` in your URI.